# vm and host on same subnet: VBox automatic: kvm how?

Tags: virtualbox, kvm

Using VirtualBox on 192.168.1.1, I get vms like 192.168.1.2 ... automatically.

kvm/virt-manager generates vms on the 192.168.122.0 subnet, with routing between 122.0 and 1.0.

AFAICT, my kvms can have addresses on the ..1.1 subnet if I configure a bridge properly.

I've yet to find a resource which says
'the minimal configuration to provide a 
kvm instance on the same subnet as the host is:'

They may be saying that, but with terminology I'm not familiar with.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Kent

Answer (score 0):

The minimum configuration is a configured bridge, as per here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KvmWithBridge

After making these changes you should have a br0 interface with an IP address, and eth0 (or whatever your setup is) should not have an IP address. Then when creating a new VM use a shared device for the networking and specify br0.

Answer (score 0):

Either a version change, or I overlooked it before:
'macvtap' options provide what I am looking for.

Thanks,
Kent